# Open Progress if NULL equivalent?

Tags: sql, openedge, progress-db

I have the below select statement but i get error

Msg 7354, Level 16, State 1, Line 393
The OLE DB provider "STREAM" for linked server "(null)" supplied invalid metadata for column "CORP_POSTINGS". The precision exceeded the allowable maximum.

```
select 
OfficeID, PostDate,
Case when a.OFFICEID in (''17'',''42'',''56'',''50'',''66'',''46'') then 
a.PROVIDERNAME else ''All Providers'' end as Provider, 
CASE WHEN a.JournalName contains ''emwell'' or a.JournalName in (''Insurance 
Refunds'') Then sum(cast(ifnull(a.Amount,0.00) as decimal (12,2))) else 0 
end as ''CORP_POSTINGS''
```

I tried ifNULL to the amount and it didnt work. I even tried ifnull and cast to decimal. Any help is greatly appreciated...

This is being done in OPEN PROGRESS ODBC CONNECTION

Comment: In standard SQL that would be `coalesce(a.Amount,0.00)` - also: the duplicated single quotes look wrong.

Comment: Which Progress OpenEdge version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have your `SUM`, `CAST`, and `IFNULL` out of order.

First, you'll want to `SUM` your amounts. Next, you'll need to `CAST` it to your target datatype (Progress seems to send the incorrect type back). Finally, if you found zero records, you'll get back `NULL`, so you'll want to `IFNULL` that to zero.

If your `a.Amount` is non-Null, it should be `IFNULL( CAST( SUM(a.Amount) AS DECIMAL(12,2) ), 0.00)`.

If your `a.Amount` CAN be Null, it should be `IFNULL( CAST( SUM( IFNULL(a.Amount, 0.00) ) AS DECIMAL(12,2) ), 0.00)`.